# Customize OS And Install

Tags: android, android-source

I am having some doubts regarding the Android OS customization process.

I would like to replace/re-brand an existing OEM device with my own home, start up and lock screens. I don't have the source code for the current OS. How do I start customizing the OS?

Is it possible to back up from the device current OS and change the code install back?

After customizing is it possible to flash the OS back to the device, with my own manufacturer certificates?

Is it requires rooting? If so after installing new OS is it possible to unroot the device, so that i can deliver the devices to the end users?

After installing custom OS, on device factory reset the stock OS or the customized OS will get restored?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I thinking your trying to make custom ROM?

Comment: No you can't just get the source code from the device. If you want to make a custom rom you have to start with the [**Android Open Source Project**](https://source.android.com/).